# Can I change the super of a class?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Is it somehow possible to choose the super of a class (preferably in the alloc or init method) so my class inherits from something else?

Comment: So you have a Volvo (car) that suddenly decides that it wants to be an elephant (animal)? :)

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You make it sound impossible...

Comment: Unless you have a very, very good understanding of both Objective-C and Cocoa internals, you should not mess with alloc

Why do you want to change the class?

Comment: Just not sure it's a good idea that's all :)

Comment: I'm writing an app which does lengthy tasks. It works fine, each task (not a subclass of NSTask) has its own object and runs its own NSTasks. That's the super. The sub just changes some variables. Now I want the user to have the option to preview the results before performing the lengthy task. But it requires a few changes in the super but I still want to have the individual changes of the sub.

Comment: Actually, class clusters do it but only by also giving you a different instance.

Comment: Hmm, after reading about it, it looks like a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in `-init` by creating an instance of the desired target class and resetting `self`. Be sure to send a `-release` message to the previous instance if you do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t. **And**: yes, you can.

A class(!) is a relative static thing. It is “hard wired” to its superclass. This is important as there must be some thing, knowing how to handle the allocated memory and other things.

Something different is an instance. You get an instance of some class by “asking” its class for one. (And, usually, after getting one you ask for initialization and so on.)

At this point the usual behaviour can be “broken”. But, as I think, **this is nothing to do for beginners**, you should be experienced when doing such tings!
Why? Read the stuff, Apple is saying about this. And see, that even Apple does such things! Have a look at class clusters like NSNumber: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) (Can’t post more than this one, but you surely find NSNumber-documentation without my help.)